# react native fetch http request throw error

Tags: http, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to make http request in react native app and it throws me an error

```
Uncaught Error: unsupported BodyInit type
at Response.Body._initBody (index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:13594)
at new Response (index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:13765)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:13820)
```

in index.js of the app I added this line

```
GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest
```

fetch request

```
            const headers = {};
        headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        let response = await fetch('https://www.saramashkim.co.il/api/get_all_product', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: headers,
            body:  null,
        })
```

when I check this url in POSTMAN it works fine and I get all data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
var headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
fetch('https://www.saramashkim.co.il/api/get_all_product', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
}).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log('response', responseJson);
  })
  .catch((error) =>{
    console.error(error);
  });
```

You can see the response is logged to console. (I've updated my answer)

repl: https://repl.it/@tejashwikalptar/samplefetchtest

Screenshot:
[image: REPL Screenshot with API result]

Comment: not sure, 'GET' method don't have any body.. so it's not the problem

Comment: Remove the body

Comment: CORS is not allowed on your URL side, so I am unable to test it, but on my local server, this is working fine

Comment: in my local server it works fine too. but I want it to work in react native app..