# How to get HTTP error detail and text from fetch and Promises?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, fetch

A lot of posts, questions and articles explain how to handle HTTP errors from fetch requests, but solutions only point `logging` or just use text of the answer, but i'd like to get response details (status + statusText) and response text (given by the server)

I want to have a generic `fetch_api` that I could use in my different components then. For the valid response it's working, but for the error I can't manage to get details + text from server, because I need to return a `rejected Promise` but I can't make it working, here are my tries to get

- response.status
- response.statusText
- response.url
- response.text() // this is a Promise and I can't get it and also the details

```
static fetch_api(url, method = 'get') {
    return fetch(url, {method: method})
        .then(res => {
            if (res.ok) return res.json();
            throw res;
        })
        .then((result) => result
            , (error) => {
                const err = ("[" + error.status + ":" + error.statusText + "] while fetching " +
                               error.url + ", response is " + error.text()) // how to get server text
                return Promise.reject(err) // ok but server text missing 
                //Er [404:NOT FOUND] while ... is [object Promise] 

                return Promise.reject().then(() => error.text()) // Not ok

                return Promise.reject(error.status)     // OK but need all

                return Promise.reject(error.statusText) // OK but need all
            }
        )
}

// USE
fetchStatus() {
    App.fetch_get(host + "/statusERROR")
       .then(result => this.setState({isLoaded: true, modules: result}))
       .catch(error => this.setState({isLoaded: true, error: {message: error}}))
}
```

Sources for basic handling, mots of them is just logging

- [react native fetch http request throw error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626431/react-native-fetch-http-request-throw-error)
- [Fetch image in React from Node.js request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473585/fetch-image-in-react-from-node-js-request)
- https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/203
- https://gist.github.com/odewahn/5a5eeb23279eed6a80d7798fdb47fe91
- https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/
- https://gist.github.com/philipszdavido/fea2e353805294f374b6cb121ce43fa5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it : use the `res.text()` promise, and return a `Promise.reject()` inside of i

```
static fetch_api(url, method = 'get') {
    return fetch(url, {method: method})
        .then(res => {
            if (res.ok) return res.json();
            throw res;
        })
        .then(result => result)
        .catch(error => error.text().then(errormsg => Promise.reject("[" + error.status + ":" +
            error.statusText + "] while fetching " + error.url + ", response is [" + errormsg+"]"))
        )
}
```

To be used like

```
App.fetch_get(host + "/status")
    .then(result => this.setState({items: result}))
    .catch(error => this.setState({error: error}}))
```